# Do not change the regular price while using a coupon in woocomerce order

Tags: php, wordpress

I using a fixed discount coupon for my woocomerce order. But the regular price may changed while applying the coupon. Is there any option to prohibit the changes in regular price and show the discount only at bottom like subtotal.
[image]

Comment: Did you set your coupon to work only with that specific product/category? or it's a cart-based discount?

Comment: Its a cart base... Problem is that the discount should not change the regular price of a product, it should be only need to display at bottom.

Comment: Could you please try to add multiple product to cart and use the discount to see what happens?

Comment: already did... discount will be shown in product price and shows a deduction.